# Distributing $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR content on scalable app

Tags: openshift

I have some static content uploaded to $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR, which is in turn served by apache with a symlink under app-root/repo/wsgi/static.

This seems to work until my app is **not** scalable, then it complain some files could not be found.

If my interpretation is correct, is there a way to put these files in the $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR and have them synced on gears at deploy time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to do this. However, we're currently investigating a solution to this for the near future. The only solution right now is to leverage something like https://github.com/boto/boto for your static files.